# Drupal: How to build a categorized menu tree

Tags: drupal, menu, taxonomy

I need to build a custom menu structure based on taxonomy terms. The Problem is that only the first level should be a Taxonomy-Term. All nested items must be a node. Each node can have only **one** Term. And Terms without any nodes associated should not appear in the menu.

How could i do that? Any suggestions for me?

**Example Menu:**

```
TERM-1
    Node-1
    Node-2
    Node-3

TERM-2
    Node-1
    Node-2

...
```

Thank you.

**Edit**
I need this for a photgrapher website. Each term is a global categorie like `Portraits`, or `Artists`. Categories are only a wrapper for galleries. Based on the example Menu above a possible structure could be something like this:

```
Series (Term)
    Bodies (Node:Type->Gallery associated with Term:Series)
    Classic Cars (Node:Type->Gallery associated with Term:Series)
    Surroundings (Node:Type->Gallery associated with Term:Series)
```

Comment: Did you had a look at "Taxonomy Menu" module ? maybe it can help you

Comment: Do you mind writing a module? Are you familiar with the basics of module-building?

Comment: Why not just a menu with terms? So when you click on a term it takes you to a fresh page with all the nodes corresponding to the term you clicked listed. Why should the nodes be in the menu?

Comment: @Tarentrulle
Taxonomy Menu is only the half way to solve the problem. I can get a nested Menu based on terms but there is no way no print the relevant nodes.

@berkes
Yes, i thougt about that but my i have only a rudimentary knowlegde about module-building.

Comment: @NoParrots: That does not work in my case because a node is a gallery. It's hard to explain just take a look: http://www.michael-dannenmann.de/business.php This is the site i'm talkin about. Currently this is a static page which needs to be ported to a drupal theme.

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler solution using views?

Comment: I just tested and think taxonomy_menu do it well, when you create a node with  a taxonomy, just add it as child of the right item in the menu.
A little developpement can do it automatically... taxonomy_menu can display node in his tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing this with a view.  You will want to create a view which lists nodes, and set the view to group by taxonomy term.

So, create a new view (admin/build/views/add)

- View Type: Node - name the view, and proceed to next page.
- Filters

  - Node: Published - yes
  - Node: Type - Gallery
  - [optional] Taxonomy: Vocabulary = Series - this will hide galleries which have not been assigned to a Series.
- Fields - delete the labels for fields as you add them

  - Taxonomy: All Terms - you could also use Taxonomy: Term, but if you have more than one taxonomy, such as free tagging, then those free tags would show up too, so All Terms is better because you can limit the vocab.

    - check the checkbox - Exclude from Display
    - limit terms by vocabulary - Series
  - Node: Title

    - check the checkbox - Link this field to its node
- Basic Settings

  - Style: Unformatted

    - click on the cog to change settings and set Grouping Field to Taxonomy: Term
  - Items to Display : 0 - since you do not want a pager, you probably want to display all the results.
- Sort Criteria - you will be adding two sort criteria...

  - Taxonomy: Weight - this controls the order for the groups - you will have to set your taxonomy term weights in the taxonomy administration area.  (You could also just sort it by Taxonomy: Term if you want the terms to appear in alphabetical order.)
  - Node: Title - this controls the order for the nodes within each group.

Answer (score 0):

[Taxonomy menu trails](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_trails) solves this problem.